# How does a SAML token look like? How to add some information to it?

Tags: authentication, active-directory, saml, saml-2.0, auth0

In the project I'm currently working on we are developing a web application which uses Auth0 to authenticate its users. We want to add the Identity Provider of the company (using ADFS) to authenticate users with Auth0 operating as a Service provider.

As you know more about the setup I'm dealing with: How does a SAML token look like? And how can I add some additional information to it (for example group memberships or permissions)? Furthermore how does Auth0 deal with this SAML token and how does it forward the information to the web application?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of token [here](http://samltool.io/).

From an ADFS perspective, ADFS is the IDP and there are claims rules that you configure that populate the token with attributes from AD.

e.g. you could pass first name, last name, UPN, email etc.

Auth0 maps these into the [user profile](https://auth0.com/docs/user-profile/user-profile-structure).

You can use Rules to augment, alter etc.